# pyOpenCV reading a video green frames

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video

I'm using py-opencv on macOS High Sierra. I'm trying to run this very simple code to read from a `.mp4` video file.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./path/to/file.mp4')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(10)
```

However, every frame shows up as solid green. I have ffmpeg 3.3.3

Comment: `ffplay ./path/to/file.mp4`. Does it play the video?

Comment: `ffplay` is not a command

Comment: Did you build ffmpeg from source or installed from repo?

Comment: It was just in my Mac already. I installed OpenCV through Anaconda

Comment: Well it's hard to know exactly if it's the OpenCV issue to FFMPEG without access to your machine. Try downloading a video from the following link and see if you can play it. http://www.h264info.com/clips.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing `opencv` from [conda-forge](https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock) and it works fine!